# Sql Join query for treeview

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, radtreeview

Hi, I have 3 Tables in my database:
[image]

[image]

I want show the select Query from this table in treeView.  I use RadTreeView, to show in treeview. I need to query by these Fields: DisplyMember | ParentMember | ChildMember.

[image]

**How do I join theses tables for this query?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your datasource would be your datagrid or list of whatever you are using to display the table. The display member would be whatever you wanted so say group name for this one. The parent member would be Groups. Value member would be groupid. I'm not real familiar with radtree view but I think this may help. Check this out too. It may help you http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/treeview-data-binding-binding-to-object-relational-data.html